# How to effectively retrieve data from Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to retrieve data from Google Places API, which is in JSON format. Each query returns a maximum of 20 results and if there are more results, there will be a "next_page_token" in the response. The token is a link to the next page of results, otherwise, it is undefined.

I have been trying to fetch the data, but haven't been able to achieve consistent results. Here is an example of my code:

```js
function getdatafirsttry(url) {
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'get'
    })
    .then(response =>
      response.json())
    .then(data => {
        next_token = data.next_page_token;

        if (next_token !== undefined) {
          url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.0333332,34.7666636&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key=...&fields=opening_hours,photos,rating.json&pagetoken=' + next_token;
          toContinue = true;
        } else {
          toContinue = false
        }
      }
      //Next page token
      function alltogheter(url) {
        getdatafirsttry(url);
      }
      getdatafirsttry(url);
```

Comment: You want to get all the data at once?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I open the web-app all the data need to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more pseudocode than actual JS, but here is the concept:

```
const yourGoogleMapsFunction = async (params you need, nextToken, listOfPlaces) => {

let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/nearbysearch/json",
    qs : {
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        pageToken: ...,
        radius: ...,
        location: ...
        ...
    },
    json: true
};

let response = await rp(options);

if (response && response.status === "OK" && response.results && response.results.length > 0) {
    listOfPlaces.push(... the results);
    yourGoogleMapsFunction(params you need, response.results...token, listOfPlaces);
}
};
```

you need to call it with {} as listOfPlaces, which will eventually hold all places

also consider limiting to a max value, in the recursion call